# TypeError: x[0] is undefined, where x is itself an array

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function part of which reads:

```
for (i = 0; i < kodoj.length; i++) {
    var x = document.getElementsByName(kodoj[i]);
    if (kodoj[i]=="zh-CN") {
        var y = document.getElementsByName("zh-TW");
        if (x[0].checked || y[0].checked) { /*do this*/ }
        else if (x[1].checked || y[1].checked) { /*do this*/ }
        else if (x[2].checked && y[2].checked) { /*continue*/ }
        else {
            alert("........");
            return;
        }
    }
    else if etc.
```

I get "x[0] is undefined", but never "x[1] or x[2] is undefined"
Having read some similar problems with declaring twodimensional arrays,
I adde in the above part of the function var x = document.getElementsByName("zh-CN");
but that did not help.
I am just a self-learning programmer, so any special features like queries and so on are not known to me.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: You should add (parts of) your HTML structure. Probably The NodeList returned by `getElementsByName()` is just empty. Furthermore, what's inside `kodoj`? As a general rule: JavaScripts stops execution at the first error encountered. That's why you don't see a `x[1] is undefined" message.

Comment: check `if(x.length)` then only check other conditions .Good if you post `html` here

Comment: Thank you. In fact it is in the program, but I left it out in the program part I sent. Also I am aware of the behaviour of Javascript when encountering an error. That is why I took out the guilty passage, after which follows some lines with x[1], x[2], another x[0], in that order. The result was that again x[0] was undefined.
About the HTML-structure: a long list, incorporated in a table, of triple radiogroups, each pertaining to the translation of a definite word into a language, telling whether the translation is similar to the translated word, or not, or inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change the value of i=0 to i=1

kodoj[0] will give you null so henceyour getting "x[0] is undefined" error

Comment: Why would kodoj[0] give null? Its content is just a sub-array of either 1 element (then it has value 0, 1 or 2, as it is a posted value from a previous page, where it was the output of a three-member radiogroup) or 3 elements (then it is a three-member boolean array, depending on a radiogroup output on the actual page)

Comment: I deleted the former comment, because that is solved now. Still I want to check whether x[0] is empty or not.
And I found. The array kodoj[i] contained 57 two- or three-letter strings and just one of them did not fit with the name under which document.getElementsByName was called: array number 32.
I have learned again ...........
I suppose I don't need your help anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that x is **not** an empty array?
You might never get "x[1] or x[2] is undefined" because execution never comes this far in the case of x being empty.